# Не открывается режим восстановления macbook

Tags: windows, macos, macbook

Когда-то поставил windows на свой macbook pro 2013 late (без bootcamp), теперь решил перейти обратно на macos, попытался войти в рекавери через command+r но открылось восстановление через интернет, может я делаю что-то не так, прошу о помощи